# Krumo output with debug()

Tags: debugging

When debugging I prefer using the [Devel](https://drupal.org/project/devel) module because of the clickable [Krumo](http://krumo.sourceforge.net/) output.

However when disabling the Devel module on production unremoved calls to e.g. `dsm()` can cause a WSOD because of calls to undefined functions.

By using the built-in [debug](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/debug/7) function this does not happen but it will miss the nice krumo output.

Is it possible to get krumo output with the debug() function / or otherwise prevent the WSOD on production sites when using devel functions?

Answer (score 2):

Use a custom code and define your own debug function that uses dsm if available or debug if not:

```
function my_debug($data, $label = NULL, $print_r = FALSE) {
  if (function_exists('dsm')) {
    dsm($data, $label);
  }
  else {
    debug($data, $label, $print_r);
  }
}
```

But keep in mind that you should avoid any debug code in production.